# Pivot selectionchanged refired

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, event-handling, pivot, selectionchanged

This problem has bugged me for 2 days now and I can't seem to solve it.

I've got a Pivot to which I add PivotItems dynamicly, depending on what's selected. Im using the SelectionChanged event and within the event handler I clear & add new items. To select the correct item afterwards Im changing the selectedindex but it seems to change outside the function afterwards. I'll submit the handler (to be noted this is a class based on the Pivot class. Mine is called CalendarPivot and the items are called CalendarPivotItem)

```
private void CalendarPivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.SelectionChanged -= CalendarPivot_SelectionChanged;

            this.zoomDate = ((CalendarPivotItem)Items.ElementAtOrDefault(SelectedIndex)).date;

            this.Items.Clear();

            this.Items.Add(new CalendarPivotItem(zoomDate, 2));
            this.Items.Add(new CalendarPivotItem(zoomDate.AddMonths(1), 2));
            this.Items.Add(new CalendarPivotItem(zoomDate.AddMonths(-1), 2));

            this.SelectedIndex = 0;

            this.SelectionChanged += CalendarPivot_SelectionChanged;
        }
```

Comment: could you try to detach the eventhandler from sender?

Comment: Tried, didnt work. The problem seems to be related to the base class changing the selectedindex after the function does

Answer (score 0):

Use `Pivot.UnloadedPivotItem` event.